# Reading text file and assigning key pair value in variable in PHP

Tags: php, file

I would like to read text file and assign left side variable to right side values. I can read the values from text file properly but can't echo $variable1.

## Text file:

```
variable1="value91";
variable2="value92";
variable3="value93";
variable4="value94";
variable5="value95";
```

## Tried code:

```
$myfile = fopen("/var/myfile", "r");
while (!feof($myfile)) {
    $line = fgets ($myfile);
    echo "$line<br/>";
}
fclose ($myfile);
```

This prints line value and can parse but how can I assign key with value so whenever I use:

## Problem:

```
echo $variable1; which will print "value91"?
```

I'm certainly fine with static assigning values to variable1, variable2 as well after reading text file if not possible dynamically using file.

Comment: Anytime your brain starts down the "Dynamically naming variables in a loop" path, think instead "Arrays". This is true in nearly every programming language.

Comment: Can you please give me hint by some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if this has bugs. I haven't written php in a good long while. Something like the following (based on my comment about using Arrays for this):

```
$myfile = fopen("/var/myfile", "r");
while (!feof($myfile)) {
    $line = fgets ($myfile);
    $lineA = explode("=", $line);
    $data[$lineA[0]]=$lineA[1];;
}
fclose ($myfile);
```

Using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to break the key and value of the line into an array.

Then adding to the new `$data` array the key/value pair from the explode.

Now after you close your file you can get your values out according to the key:

```
echo $data["variable1"];
```

Which should echo out `value91`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ability to use a string as the target of assignment, so ...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$lines = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    $data = explode("=", $line);
    $varName = $data[0];
    $$varName = $data[1];
}

echo $variable1;
```

Note the assignment is using $$varName, so it uses the first column as the name of the variable.

This outputs-

```
"value91"
```